# Tableless web design

Tags: html, html-table

I know that HTML tables are bad, but I have designed my site using them. Here is an example:

```
<h2><a name="tutorials">Tutorials:</a></h2>
<table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="lcol"/>
        <col class="rcol"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article529.html">Link</a></td>
        <td><b>LDraw to SimCity 3000 Unlimited Tutorial:</b> A tutorial describing how to import LDraw models into <i>SimCity 3000 Unlimited</i>.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article528.html">Link</a></td>
        <td><b>Polarized Glasses Tutorial:</b> A tutorial describing how to render LDraw models (and other POV-Ray scenes) so that they can be viewed in 3D using <a target="_blank" href="http://www.chromatek.com/">Chromatek</a> polarized glasses.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article545.html">Link</a></td>
        <td><b>Cleaning LDraw Models for Export:</b> A tutorial describing why it is hard to clean LDraw models for export to other formats and applications.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
```

Now, how do I get rid of tables such as these yet still retain the same tabular "look"? Thanks.

Comment: If the data belongs in a table, leave it in a table.

Comment: You are not providing us with the complete package in order to recreate your circumstances, also you should read up on how to create a layout with divs instead of tables. Good thing that you're stepping away from tables for designing your websites, you should have done that 4 or so years ago ;)

Comment: That does look like tabular data, though ...

Comment: [Here's a link](http://isometricland.net/lego/lego.php) to the page where the above example is from. I don't consider it true data. It's just links and brief descriptions of the pages being linked to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a coding request, and with insufficient data at that.

Comment: I reworded my intro post. The example fits the scope of my problem, since my site is filled with tables such as these.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand why it was closed. User @Aru seems to have understood the scope of my problem, though I don't necessarily agree with his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this using dl dt dd

**HTML**

```
<h2><a name="tutorials">Tutorials:</a></h2>
<div class="tabular_data">
    <dl> <dt><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article529.html">Link</a></dt>
        <dd><b>LDraw to SimCity 3000 Unlimited Tutorial:</b> A tutorial describing how to import LDraw models into <i>SimCity 3000 Unlimited</i>.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl> <dt><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article528.html">Link</a></dt>
        <dd><b>Polarized Glasses Tutorial:</b> A tutorial describing how to render LDraw models (and other POV-Ray scenes) so that they can be viewed in 3D using <a target="_blank" href="http://www.chromatek.com/">Chromatek</a> polarized glasses.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl> <dt><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ldraw.org/Article545.html">Link</a></dt>
        <dd><b>Cleaning LDraw Models for Export:</b> A tutorial describing why it is hard to clean LDraw models for export to other formats and applications.</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabular_data{
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom:2px solid gray;
}
.tabular_data dl, .tabular_data dd, .tabular_data dt {
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
}
.tabular_data dl {
    border-spacing:0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .tabular_data dl {
        border-spacing:5px 5px;
        display:table;
    }
    .tabular_data dd, .tabular_data dt {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .tabular_data dt {
        width:15%;
    }
    .tabular_data dd {
        width:84%;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjvk96nh/)

Comment: What does the @media line do? I haven't studied up on CSS3 yet. Also, is this not just another abuse of semantics like the one I was trying to avoid in the first place?

Comment: @media represent the media query used respond the page irrespective of the screen size, try the above sample by reducing/resizing the screen width (try to toggle the screen width) to get a clear view.. check this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/